# How the make the JWT signature same for the same user with different keys

Tags: express, ecmascript-6, jwt, express-jwt

I am basically creating a server for authentication(sign-in/sign-up) where I am storing my hashed password in the database with the user during sign-up.

**Sign-up Code**

```
async function user_signup(user_name, pass_word) {
  //finding existing users
  const user_exist = await add_people.findOne({ username: user_name });
  if (user_exist) {
    return null; 
  }

  //creating a instance to push into the database
  const passable = new add_people({
    username: user_name,
    password: hasher(user_name, pass_word),
  });

  //saving and returning true
  passable.save();
  return true;
}
```

And during login, I am getting the username and password, hashing it and comparing it to the hash stored in my database.

**Login Code**

```
async function login(user_name, pass_word) {

  //finding whether the user exists or not
  const user_exist = await add_people.findOne({ username: user_name });
  const hashed = hasher(user_name, pass_word);

  if (user_exist.password === hashed) {
    return hashed;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Now the main issue is that, the hashes generated by both of these functions are different (the signature part). I tried looking up the documentations and `https://jwt.io` but the only thing I could figure out was to make it the same, I got to convert the signature to base64 encoded.

I have no idea how to code this out. Can y'all please tell me how I can implement this or a better way to do what I intend to do. Thank you.

EDIT: here is the code of my hasher

```
function hasher(user_name, pass_word) {
  const hash = jwt.sign(
    { username: user_name, password: pass_word },
    awt_global_pass
    });
  return hash;
}
```

Comment: Even after reading 3 times, I don't see what password hashing has to do with JWT signatures. Also in your code, I don't see anything about JWT.

Comment: Signature? JWT? Keys? Wth is your `hasher`?

Comment: Why are you even passing the `user_name` to the `hasher`? You should be using salt and pepper.

Comment: @jps I am talking the username and password and converting it to a JsonWebToken using the inbuilt `sign` function by passing in my payload along with my secret key.

When passing my username and password with the secret key, the header and payload of my JWT remains the same and only the signature keeps changing with every iteration of running the `sign` function with the exact same parameters

Comment: I also attached my hasher function above ^

Comment: Sounds like a typical [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me. The JWT signature changes, because the JWT contains timestamps for creation and expiration. You could create a JWT without timestamps, but honestly the whole thing doesnt't make sense. If you encode your username and password in the JWT and store the JWT it means that anyone with access to the db could read the passwords (they are just base64 encoded in the payload of the JWT). Forget the JWT thing and look for password hashing.